# Type 1 Memory error with PT60M interval only

Tags: php, time

I am getting a memory error in my while loop when I use 60 as my `$interval` and `$service_duration` is 30 or less but all other numbers seem to work fine. I also notice that it only occurs when the interval between start and end times is a fraction of an hour such as a 9:30 interval in my example below.

The memory error is:

> E_ERROR : type 1 -- Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) -- at line 15

This only happens with 60 as my `$interval` as explained above. Line 15 contains `$interval`.

`$service_duration` and `$interval` need to be able to vary in time and 60 and 30 are an important time segments to get right.  This is stripped down example of the code I am using:

```
<?php
$interval=60;
$service_duration=30;
$selected_time = '11:00';
$time1 = new DateTime($selected_time);
$start_hour=$time1;
$end_time = '20:30';
$time2 = new DateTime($end_time);
$end_hour=$time2;
$current_hour=$start_hour;
$diff = $current_hour->diff($end_hour);

while (($diff->h * 60 + $diff->i) >= intval($service_duration)) {
    $available_hours[] = $current_hour->format('H:i');
    $current_hour->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $interval . 'M')); # line 15
    $diff = $current_hour->diff($end_hour);
}

$x=count($available_hours)-1;
$y=0;
while ($y<=$x) {
    echo  $available_hours[$y] .'<br />';
    $y++;
}
?>
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gs1g-quwf

I need to stop this memory error and I am stumped.  What is wrong with 60 here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue was that the diff always returns a positive number, even when it is negative.  So it went into an infinite loop.  I simply needed to add a line to catch when the diff was inverting the negative then break the loop.  So the modified code is:

```
<?php
$interval=60;
$service_duration=30;
$selected_time = '11:00';
$time1 = new DateTime($selected_time);
$start_hour=$time1;
$end_time = '20:30';
$time2 = new DateTime($end_time);
$end_hour=$time2;
$current_hour=$start_hour;
$diff = $current_hour->diff($end_hour);

while (($diff->h * 60 + $diff->i) >= intval($service_duration)) {
        $available_hours[] = $current_hour->format('H:i');
    $current_hour->add(new DateInterval('PT' .$interval. 'M'));
    $diff = $current_hour->diff($end_hour);
    if ($diff->invert == 1) {  
     break;
    }
}

$x=count($available_hours)-1;
$y=0;
    while ($y<=$x){
    echo  $available_hours[$y] .'<br />';
    $y++;
}
?>
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sy4y-vp2v

All is well now.